# Sums the squares of the positive integers in a List that are divisible by three or seven, ignoring other data types

Tags: python

I tried with a lot of options but the output is not coming. please refer my code and attached screenshots herewith.

```
   def Squares(aList):
    x=0
    
    for element in aList:
        #x=0
        if type(element)==int and element>0:
            if (element)%3==0 or (element)%7==0:
                x=x+element**2
        else:
            pass
        return x
print(Squares([[1,5,-3,5,9,8,14,-25]]))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Include any necessary text in the text of your question.

Comment: **We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow.** Please post all text as ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) text. Read more [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Questions with images of text/code/errors are routinely closed. Please also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the question guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure this & your future questions are suitable for this Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two errors:

1. you call your function with a list of lists
2. you return within the loop, meaning you return after the first element of the list

```py
def Squares(aList):
    x=None
    
    for element in aList:
        #x=0
        if type(element)==int and element>0:
            if x is None:
                x=0
            if (element)%3==0 or (element)%7==0:
                x=x+element**2
        else:
            pass
    return x
print(Squares([1,5,-3,5,9,8,14,-25]))
```

yields the expected output.

A more pythonic way of doing the task is

```py
import numbers
def Squares(aList):
    numeric_list = [el for el in aList if isinstance(el, numbers.Number)]
    if not numeric_list:
        return None
    squared_filtered_list = [el**2 for el in numeric_list if el > 0 and (el%3 == 0 or el%7==0)]
    return sum(squared_filtered_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for 2 outputs but if input is not a list then None is not coming as a output. Nothing is returned if the input is not a list. Note that the keyword None is not the
string ‘None'.

Comment: thats because you initialize x = 0 in the beginning before the type check

Comment: where i have to initialize x then for getting output as True for print(sumSquares('5') is None)